How to Set Mathptmx as the Main Font Among Others Using Fontspec?
This question is motivated by David Carlisle's answer in Does \setmainfont{Times New Roman} Produce Very Close to the Real Thing?:
I have a latex document in which I invoke several fonts, some of which I call in from time to time in the code.
I would like to make mathptmx them main font. If I used no other fonts, then I should be able to simply invoke the mathptmx package and that (I think) should be sufficient to have the entire document be typeset in mathptmx.
However, since I have several fonts (some of which require fontspec), I tried something based on the following MWE which I compile with lualatex:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{mathptmx}

\begin{document}
One Two Three \textsc{Four Five Six}
\end{document}

Unfortunately, I get an error message telling me that "the font `mathptmx'" cannot be found.
If I run the above code without the \setmainfont{mathptmx} command, the code compiles without error.
How may I invoke the fontspec package while setting mathptmx as the main font?

The answer here is "don't do that"  mathptmx is a legacy 8 bit font package setting up several fonts (not "a font" for 8 bit classic tex) it is deprecated even for pdftex and not usable at all via fontspec which is about specifying Unicode OpenType and TrueType fonts.

"mathptmx" is not a font at all (and certainly not an OpenType font) so it is hard to guess the intention here. If the intention is to use a times like setup that works for pdftex and luatex use \usepackage{newtx} as previously stated.

You can load OpenType versions of the exact variant of Times used in mathptmx with:
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeXGyreTermesX}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

If you have any trouble with that, you could optionally insert the following command between \usepackage{unicode-math} and loading TeXGyreTermesX:
\defaultfontfeatures[TeXGyreTermesX]{
    Ligatures={Common,TeX},
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    SlantedFont=*-Slanted,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
    BoldSlantedFont=*-BoldSlanted,
    Extension=.otf}

Aside: It’s strange to me to see people consider Times New Roman “the real thing.”  It’s a newer clone of Times Roman, like the name says.

mathptmx is not a font, it is a package for pdftex or latex (not lualatex) that sets up a legacy Times Roman font setup based on the fonts available in a 1990s postscript printer.
It is still usable (but far from recommended) with pdflatex, but should not be used with luatex and completely unrelated to any fonts loaded by fontspec which handles Unicode OpenType fonts.
To define a document setup using Times Roman style fonts foe text and math using suitable fonts (in each case) for pdflatex and lualatex use
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{newtx}


\begin{document}
One Two Three \textsc{Four Five Six}
\end{document}

If used with luatex the newtx package will use the TeX Gyre Termes and Tex Gyre Termes Math  opentype fonts.
If used with pdflatex it uses the tx fonts which are 8-bit tex-specific subset type 1 fonts derived from the TeX Gyre Opentype.

Yes, but how may I (1) call in the several (alluded to earlier) fonts which require fontspec; and  then (2) set newtx as the main font?

newtx is not a font it is a package, it simply calls fontspec and uses \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} (and a few other similar setup commands), so you can just add whatever other fontspec commands you need after loading the package. @Jethro

@Jethro the code above is most likely all you need, if you need some sans serif (Arial-style) text  just use {\sffamily some sans serif text here} of you really do need specific fontspec commands (you have not shown any) then just use them, you can use \newfontfamily\foo{some-opentype-font}  fontspec commands in the document I show here.
